# Этимология "вестимо"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/вестимо](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE):

> **Этимология**
>
> Происходит от ??

От чего?

Comment: Вопрос-то в чём, можете сформулировать проблему? Зачем даёте ссылку, что за двоеточие...

Comment: Это такая запись  в Википедии по ссылке, то есть там нет сведений  по этимологии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вести́мо** (*прост., устар.* и *обл.*) — вводное слово и частица; значение: само собой разумеется, конечно, известно.

Стоящая информация об этимологии, считаю, имеется в интересной статье Ю. А. Шкураток ["Семантические различия глаголов *věděti и *znati в праславянском и древнерусском языках"](http://www.rfp.psu.ru/archive/4.2012/shkuratok.pdf):

> Проанализируем семантическое наполнение других прилаг. с корнем *věd-:
> <...>
> ***вѣстимый*** имеет значение ‘известный’: *То велие чюдо намъ не вестимо, а ведомо то велие чюдо Даниле пророку.* Сл. о ц. Мих. XVII в. [СлРЯ XI–XVII вв. 2: 52]...

Věděti → вѣдать → ве́дать (знать, иметь сведения; устаревший вариант: он, она, оно — *весть*; бог весть где, бог весть когда) → вести́мый → вестимо.

*– Дык как же я сочтусь за товар твой, княже, пока покупатель его не осмотрит и задатка не даст? Опять же тебе, **вестимо,** здешние монеты надобны, а не русские* (А. Прозоров. Последняя битва).

P. S. Иногда является [усеченным прилагательным](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1744/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5):
*― **Вестимо** дело, жену кто ж не учит, ― отозвалась продавщица Таисия* (В. Войнович. Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина).

Answer (score 1):

Вестимо - от весть, вестИ, вещь, вещий.

Я бы обозначил корень как ве-, а далее будет стоять сильный, либо слабый согласный набор(ст/щ - глухие и шипяще-свистящие).

Сильный согласный ве+Д - ведать, ведать, это понимать суть чего-то, как написано в статье приведенной у Риммы Михайловны, обладать "тайным знанием". На самом деле никой особой тайны нет, потому что "тайное знание"(mystery knowledge) это всего лишь вкусить/отведать суть чего-то, увидеть то, что внутри.

С другой стороны ве+сть, ве+щ - не является основой понимания, а является только проводником, эхом, знанием о - разнести весть, известить(информировать). Вестимо - знакомо, узнаваемо. Знак не обязательно понимать, достаточно обладать информацией о значении, чтобы значимая вещь могла овеществится, проявится в мире. А ведомо - понятно, познано, вид+им(о). Извести - сообщить новость, без какой-либо взаимности, уведомить - донести до понимания сути проблемы/заручится подтверждением, что кто-то извещен - более сильная форма действия.

Ведущий - это главный, имеющий понимание дела, понимание куда собственно ведёт, ведомый - тот кого ведут, внемлющий ведущему, вести - руководить(скорее всего водить тоже однокоренное, так как в записи слово отсутствовала гласная буква между В и Д, и вИд+еть также является однокоренным). Современное модное слово являющееся аналогом слова весть - информация, "ВЕсти" - новостная передача, "ИзвЕстия" - газета. Вестимо - то есть, "да, это мне/нам знакомо / да, это я знаю".

Одна из самых древних книг, сборник священных, религиозно-философских текстов в индуизме, называется Ве́ды. Так что скорее всего слово ведать, ВЕД, имеет санскритскую этимологию. Однако, оглушение данного корня и произношение его как вест/вещ для выражения неполноты смысла - это чисто наше изобретение.

Вестник смерти - ангел, который сообщает о смерти кого-то, забирает душу, сам смертью не являющийся. Вестник - агент, распространяющий информацию.

Ведь+ма - обладающая пониманием женщина, ведующая, ведунья, а знахарка - обладающая знанием и потому умеющая лечить, от знать + харк/харь(харкать, плеваться? или харя - лицо? или кара - рок?)

Можно также оценить народный юмор при образовании слова врач - врать, не совсем лгать, а сообщать вздор, чепуху, то есть нести не весть что, не знамо что, рассказывать про каких-то невидимых вредителей(микробов) и тд.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, мне очень хотелось услышать ваше мнение относительно корня в словах ведать и вести. Надо еще в словаре Черных посмотреть.

Comment: @Sharon мне единственное, что не нравится у Черных, что ведать ~ знать. Знать - это слабая или неполная форма, знать - воспринимать знак, а ведать - понимать суть, через обладание знанием, познание. Я использую образ коробки с надписью, вот есть коробка, на ней надпись - марка, даже бренд. Умение читать надпись - это знание, о предназначении коробки, но знание не гарантирует, что содержание коробки, то что внутри, соответствует надписи на ней. Потому что внутри - тайное знание, скрытое. Ведать - это знать не то, что на(название) коробке, а то что в(внутри) коробке.

Comment: Да и еще не переживать, а проживать. Не знаю, почему такие неточности.